# Can we push local variable to stack in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I made a simple program which will just push a number and display it on the screen but 
don't know what is going wrong

```
section .data
value db 10

section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
push 10   //can we push value directly on stack?
call printf
add esp,4
ret
```

Getting Segmentation fault for above.

```
section .data
value db 10

section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
push [value]   
call printf
add esp,4
ret
```

In second version will be pushing value pointed to by value variable on to stack

But getting "operation size not specified"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can push any DWORD value (in 32-bit assembler) onto the stack.

The problem in the first code fragment is that `printf` expects the first argument to be a format string (in C, you'd write `printf("%d\n", 10);`). So something like

```
 section .data
 fmt db "%d", 10, 0

 ...
 push 10
 push fmt
 call printf
 add esp, 8
```

will work.

In the second code fragment, instead of `push [value]` you should write `push dword [value]`, but that's not correct if your `value` variable is a single byte. Either declare it as a DWORD (`dd`), or perform

```
movsx eax, byte [value] ; if it's a signed integer; movzx for unsigned
push eax
```

And one more thing. When calling `printf` (or any of the C library functions), beware of stack alignment. Some platforms require that stack is 16-byte aligned at the time of a function call (this is necessary for correct execution of optimized CPU instructions like SSE). So, to make the stack aligned:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 8   ; reserve 8 bytes for parameters
and esp, -16 ; align the stack (the reserved space can increase)
mov dword [esp], fmt   ; put parameters into stack
mov dword [esp+4], 10
call printf
mov esp, ebp ; restore stack
pop ebp
```

Comment: Thanks @Inspired for your answer,I thing I would to know is there anything apart from printf to print values on to the screen in assembly,I mean alternate of printf.

Comment: And even after changing value size to dw,I am getting "operation size not specified"

Comment: You MUST specify operand size in `push` (since there are `push word` and `push dword` commands): write `push dword [value]`. And regarding printing integers without `printf` - I haven't heard about such functions, but you can define your own function that will use `printf` with `"%d"` (or `"%u"` specifier).

Comment: Of course you can print values without using `printf`! You think `printf` knows some instructions that we don't? You'll have to convert the value to text - a '1' and a '0', in this case. Then just print it. You don't specify OS, but it looks like Linux to me... so `sys_write`, perhaps. Or `WriteFile` for 'doze? It is fairly easy to screw this up. `printf` was written by trained professionals. You know, the folks who brought us `gets()`! :)